# How do I auto-indent in emacs when opening a file?

Tags: java, linux, emacs, formatting, gnu

I'm currently working in Java with a team. Whenever we share files, their files are always indented weirdly on my computer, and I have to either tab through them all or C-x h C-M-.

Is there a way to make it so that emacs will automatically format (auto-tab the whole file) whenever I open the file, so I don't have to enter that macro every time?

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you're working in a team, I assume you're using version control? In which case you're talking about committing modifications throughout a file in order to change from their indentation method to your indentation method. And presumably they will then change it back. That'd be awful -- the code changes in the diffs will be obscured by a mess of white-space changes. Make a team decision about formatting, and get everyone to configure their editors to comply to that. (All that aside, are you sure that you don't just have a different tab-width to them? Maybe that's all you need to configure.)

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://editorconfig.org/ (and as it's java, see also https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/issues/86 which indicates a completed netbeans plugin, and the beginnings of an eclipse plugin).

Comment: I think it might just be a formatting issue. The tab width doesn't appear to be it. I don't think they see an issue, as my resolution is rather high, and my terminal is more zoomed in than the default.

Comment: You might like to edit a representative before/after example into your question, so we can see what's actually going on. Re-indenting entire source files just sounds **wrong**, so there may be a better way, but it's hard to know without seeing some code. (I'm assuming, of course, that the original code appears to be formatted sanely when your team mates view it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in your ~/.emacs:

```
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook (lambda () (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))))
```

This registers a function to be executed when the Java major mode is entered, and that function is a lambda expression that indents the region between `(point-min)` and `(point-max)` -- i.e., the entire buffer.

It will be loaded the next time you start emacs. To get it into the running session, put the cursor behind it and  press C-x C-e.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly what I was looking for ^^

Shortest and most effective solution I've seen.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar problems when working in emacs alongside non-emacs coders. I was seeing "weirdness" due to emacs' default tab indention being set to 8 columns instead of 4. Setting your tab width to 4 should fix this. You can enter **M-x whitespace-mode** to look at your whitespace characters and see if that's the problem. If so, you can add the following to your init file to fix it:

```
(setq-default tab-width 4) ;; emacs version 23.2+
(setq default-tab-width 4) ;; emacs versions prior to 23.2
```

When I need to re-indent a file, I call the following function from my init file with **M-x iwb**:

```
(defun iwb ()
  "indent whole buffer"
  (interactive)
  (delete-trailing-whitespace)
  (indent-region (point-min) (point-max))
  (untabify (point-min) (point-max)))
```

A hook could be added for this function similar to [Wintermute's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4301306/wintermute) reponse.

```
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook #'iwb)
```